# Drools rule issue after migrating to 6.x from 5.3

Tags: drools

I am getting issue in below rule. This is working fine in 5.3 but throwing error (must be boolean expression).

```
     String drl="import com.drools.Applicant;"
            + "rule \"Is of valid age\"  "
            + " when $a : Applicant(age > 18 && name matches \"(?i).*\"+ name + \"(.|\n|\r)*\")"
            + " then $a.setValid( true );  "
            + " System.out.println(\"validation: \" + $a.isValid());\n"+
              "end";
```

Issue is with line :
" when $a : Applicant(age > 18 && name matches \"(?i).*\"+ name + \"(.|\n|\r)*\")"

Any advise.

Comment: Please explain what the second term of the constraint is supposed to do? Note that there's a difference in the regular expression between the code snippet and the text after "Issue is..."

Answer (score 1):

The expression isn't correct since `name` cannot be resolved as part of an experssion. Use a binding.

```
$a : Applicant($n: name, age > 18, name matches \"(?i).*\"+ $name + \"(.|\n|\r)*\")"
```

(I don't think the the constraint makes much sense - it's merely a test whether a name matches itself, with or without arbitrary characters before and after. Moreover, the `?i` is superfluous.)

Comment: Hey Laune,True. This is legacy code and unfortunately dont know the purpose.  It gets tricky to resolve in such situations when underlying intent is unclear. For now placing "(" after "matches" and ")" at the end worked out. Thanks for the help